# How does scanf interact with the the Carriage Return character, New Line Feed character, and Enter button on a Windows 10 OS

Tags: c, input, scanf, ascii

I just want to preface this inquiry with the recognition that most people have a contemptuous view of the `scanf` function in C. (I have seen many places that strongly discourage the usage of this function). However, the book that I am reading (*C Programming: A Modern Approach*) relies heavily on this function for at least the first 250 pages. With that disclaimer out of the way...

---

I am using a Windows 10 operating system (which I think may be relevant for this question based on some of the literature search I have gone through prior to writing this question).

I am interested in understanding the distinction between Carriage Returns `\r`, new line feeds `\n`, and the **Enter** key in the context of how they interact with `scanf`. The following snippet of code is what I want to focus on:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() 
{
  int N = 3;
  int b[N];
  int i;
  printf("Enter %d numbers: ", N);
  for (i=0; i < N; i++)
    scanf("%d", &b[i]);
  printf("The recorded input stream was ");
  for (i=0; i < N ; i++)
    printf("%d ",b[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

After compiling (using `gcc`) and running the code (on the command prompt), the user is prompted to enter 3 numbers. Now, consider the following four possible entries:

1. `1` **Enter** `2` **Enter** `3` **Enter**
2. `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8` **Enter**
3. `1 \n 2 \n 3` **Enter**
4. `1 \r 2 \r 3` **Enter**

The outputs for each above case are as follows:

1. `The recorded input stream was 1 2 3`
2. `The recorded input stream was 1 2 3`
3. `The recorded input stream was 1 4199520 1956891840`
4. `The recorded input stream was 1 4199520 1956891840`

Could someone please explain these 4 cases? (I have some guesses, but I'd rather hear the exact mechanism than post my own speculative drivel). Thank you!

Comment: If you actually typed a backslash followed by an `n`, then the second and third calls to `scanf` will fail. Always check the return value from `scanf`. Since you're asking for one conversion, `scanf` should return 1. Anything else is a failure. Also note that the sequence `\n` only has meaning when it's part of your source code. It means nothing to `scanf`, other than it's not a number.

Comment: @user3386109 Thank you. Could you explain why the "Enter" button is treated differently?

Comment: The terminal holds the input in a line buffer until Enter is pressed. This allows the user to edit the input before submitting it. After Enter is pressed, the line is available for `scanf` to process. `scanf` will only take what it needs to satisfy the conversion requests.

Comment: @user3386109 I understand this much. But I guess my question is, "how is the Enter button interpreted by scanf...and how does that interpretation differ from `\n` and `\r`?"

Comment: The Enter button is treated as white space by `scanf`. `scanf` ignores whitespace, except when it doesn't, which is why *"people have a contemptuous view"* of `scanf`.

Comment: @user3386109 sorry for the confusion in terminology...but I thought \n and \r were also “white spaces”. Further, I thought that the space bar, which can be written as the character ‘ ‘ is also a white space.

Comment: The problem is that your examples 3 and 4, and the corresponding outputs for those examples indicate that you haven't fully grasped what `\r` and `\n` are. Carriage returns and line feeds are treated as whitespace by `scanf`. That much is true.

Comment: @user3386109 sorry but you’ve totally lost me. You say that scanf ignores white spaces, agree that new line feeds and return carriages are white spaces, but then state that scanf responds to Enter, which is a white space...but \n and \r, which are the symbolic representations of white spaces, are treated differently by scanf. Not sure I understand.

Comment: Yes, I know. You need to reread my very first comment one hundred times, and maybe the light bulb will come on. Otherwise, you're going to need a tutor to explain it to you.

Comment: @user3386109 I guess you are saying something along the lines of “symbolic representations of white spaces are handled differently by scanf than their actual corresponding keyboard key”. For example, \t and the tab button are treated differently by scanf. If that is accurately capturing your comments, then I still have the question of WHY those are interpreted differently.

Comment: Ok, good. They are interpreted differently because escape sequences are only defined in the context of the source code of a C program. In other words, part of the preprocessor's job is to look for those escape sequences, and replace them with the corresponding character codes. Outside of C source code, those escape sequences have no special meaning. So if you tell `scanf` to look for a number (using `%d`) and you type a backslash followed by an `n`, `scanf` will read the backslash as a backslash. It will note that a backslash cannot be part of a number, and will stop.

Comment: @user3386109 thanks for sticking with me! I think I get what you’re saying. If you’re willing, one last bit of confirmation: the new line feed has an ASCII code representation of 10 (in decimal). The preprocessor, before compilation, will convert the symbol ‘\n’ to the ASCII code 10. The “10” here is what actually tells the compiler what to do. NOT the ‘\n’ symbol. When scanf sees ‘\n’ it actually sees the ASCII codes for ‘\’ and ‘n’ as distinct, individual entities. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's it!

Comment: @user3386109 lol. Your methods of making me work for it are not my preference, but I greatly appreciate the “guided” insight nonetheless. Cheers~

Comment: I wasn't making you work for it. My very first comment has all the information that my last comment has. Communication is based on shared experience, and in your experience `\n` was always treated as a single entity. I needed to somehow get you to separate `\ ` from `n`. Anyhow, we got there. Cheers.